# MPEG-4 Mediainfo, what's "Format Profile"?

Tags: file-formats, mpeg4

I'm wondering what the Format Profile tag/field refers to.

(Backstory: I have a couple MPEG-4 videos (I made) on a NAS which won't stream through my X-box 360 (but will stream on any other computer, ditto a Roku box) so I ran them through mediainfo to see if there were any difference with other videos that stream fine  -- made with the same settings.)

Format Profile shows a value of "Sony PSP" which is odd to me, since I've not intentionally chosen anything to do Sony. I'm making these with a custom profile I made (from a very slightly tweaked preset in Powerdirector) that's pretty much a medium-high quality 720p x.264 profile. I assume that powerdirector is somehow filling in that field (though I can't see it anywhere in the settings for the profile) or is this something that Mediainfo is assuming based on the characteristics of the video?